# What is the transparent shadow in my mesh?

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface

I am new at Blender and I was having difficulty using the Subdivision Surface modifier because somehow while making the whole thing I messed up the underlying mesh. (For instance, there were some gaps at some places i.e. the vertices were not joined)

I am now trying to fix the mesh and there seems to be a transparent shadow at some parts when I zoom in the edit mode.I think I may have some extra vertices on top of the mesh vertices but I am not sure.

Please look the following image.
[image]

As one can see, there is a whitish shadow on the mesh. I do not know what that is or how to remove it.

Comment: It's hard to say from just this image, could you share this part of the mesh through https://blend-exchange.com/ ?

Comment: Most likely an accidental n-gon. Switch to face select mod and you should be able to spot and delete it.